# AucTeX/emacs unable to find a package

Tags: packages, auctex, paths

In my current LaTeX document I am using the "classico" package, which sets the classico font for a document (this means I can use plain LaTeX instead of xeTeX).  I can compile the document with pdfLaTeX fine from the command line.  But in Emacs, with aucTeX, I get the error:

```
ERROR: LaTeX Error: File `classico.sty' not found.
```

When I run `kpsewhich classico.sty` it comes back with

```
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/classico/classico.sty
```

However, `kpsewhich geometry.sty` (which *is* found by aucTeX) returns

```
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
```

So it seems that packages in the `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/` tree are not being properly picked up, whereas the packages in the `/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/` are.

How can I adjust aucTeX so that it can find the packages in the first tree?

Comment: Strange. But maybe you have put something into your init file (e.g. .emacs). Close Emacs and restart it from command line with `emacs -Q`, open your file, switch to latex-mode (`M-x latex-mode RET`) and compile. If compiling succeeds, there is a command in your init file, which prevents loading the local tree. Or do you have by chance another TeX-installation or another local tree on your system?

Comment: Which OS are you running on?  For MacOS you may want to use the `exec-path-from-shell` package to import your standard shell environment variables.